# how can i generate 0's in stair case in 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

In 2D array we can generate n*n matrix. and how can replace number into 0's replace in the matrix.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 8;
        int coulmns = 4;
        int array;
        for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < coulmns; j++) {

               System.out.print(i*j+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

output:

```
1 2 3 
2 4 6 
3 6 9 
4 8 12 
5 10 15 
6 12 18 
7 14 21
```

how can i replace as 0's in stair case in the form of output:

```
1 2 (0) 
2 (0) 6 
(0) 6 9 
4 (0) 12 
5 10 (0) 
6 (0) 18 
(0) 14 21
```

Answer (score 0):

I  assume the language is Java as that is the tag specified.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class StairCase
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int rows = 8;
        int coulmns = 4;
        int col=3;
        int row=1;
        int flag=0;
        int array;
        for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < coulmns; j++) {
                if(col==j && row==i){
                    System.out.print("(0)");
                    if(col>1 && col<4 && flag==0){
                        col--;
                        if(col==1){
                            flag=1;
                        }
                        row++;
                    }else{
                        col++;
                        if(col==3){
                            flag=0;
                        }
                        row++;
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.print(i*j+" ");  
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

**Result :**

1 2 (0)

2 (0) 6

(0) 6 9

4 (0) 12

5 10 (0)

6 (0) 18

(0) 14 21

Comment: can you give explanation please

Comment: First You have to check one row contains only one (0). Then if it's the end of the row then decrease the variable named col. Else if it is equals to first column then increase the count till it reaches to the end of the column , again repeat this till you reach upto the last row.

Answer (score -1):

In the second for loop try doing this:

```
for (int j = 1; j < coulmns; j++) {
   int number = i*j;

   if(i == 3 || i == 7) number = 0;
   else if((j == 3 && i == 1) || (j == 3 && i == 5)) number = 0;
   else if((j == 2 && i == 2) || (j == 2 && i == 6)) number = 0;
   else System.out.print(number + " ");
}
```

You can also use modulus if you want.

Answer (score -2):

I assume the language is Java as that is the tag specified.

I think the solution will be to use modulus arithmetic.

You want to replace the value in the cell position (4 - row number % 4) with (0).  Where (row number % 4) = 0 then the (0)always goes in the second cell.  So the code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 8;
        int coulmns = 4;
        int array;
        for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < coulmns; j++){
               if((j == (4 - (i % 4)) || (i % 4 == 0 && j == 2)))
               {
                 System.out.print("0 ");
               }
               else
               {
               System.out.print(i*j+" ");
               }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Fair enough, it was my first ever answer so I wanted to get a general idea posted in time while I worked out the code !

Comment: @GBishton thank you it works. can you give brief explanation please.

Comment: Thanks, the reason for using modulus is that it is extensible for any number of rows.

Comment: Sure the explanation for using modulus is that using a remainder is good for a staircase pattern like this and it saves having to hold multiple increment / decrement counters (write less code...)